# Ensure a valid date inside the cell in Excel

Tags: excel, parsing, date, excel-2010

I am trying to prepare a list of credit card transactions for pivoting and further analysis in Excel 2010 (for personal needs). Problem is that my banking institution does not follow a standard date format, so sometimes dates will be coming as `Jun. 1, 2013`, and sometimes as `May 27, 2013`. The first is not recognized as a date by Excel, so its Pivot cannot *Group* on that (month, quarter etc.). There are no other unrecognized date occurrences in the list.

**Is there a way to ensure there is always a valid date in a column?**

If I were coding in .NET, one option would be use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a format string `MMM. d, yyyy`.

Another option is to do an `If`, to convert any string to a date in a  something like:

```
If Not TypeOf MyCell Is DateTime Then _
  MyCell.Value = CDate(MyCell.Value.Substring(0,3) &
                       MyCell.Value.Substring(3))
```

(This is VB.NETish pseudo-syntax, hope it helps explain my intention). It assumes that a non-valid date will always be a string with a dot inside it, to be removed by the converter - which I am okay with.

**How would I do this in Excel?** Looking for the most simple approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your date is in `A1`, this formula will convert it to time-serial format:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))
```

You can then format it to whatever format you want.

Another option is to use this UDF:

```
Function MorphDate(strDate As String) As Date
    Application.Volatile
    If VarType(strDate) <> 8 Then Exit Function
    Res = Replace(strDate, ".", "")
    MorphDate = Res
End Function
```

Use like so: `=MorphDate(A1)`, and format it to whatever format you want.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to put an if statement there? i.e. if not a date already, do the conversion? Otherwise do nothing on a cell.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are many checks the can be made, but seeing as how the `.` turns it solely into a string, we just check its `VarType`. If it returns `String` or `8`, then we convert it, otherwise, it is what it is. Check my edit above. :)

Comment: As a C# developer, it's weird to see this syntax, i.e. passing a date value boxed as a string (imposibru!), then doing a type check against a string, i.e. `If TypeOf String Is a Date`... but amazingly enough, it works perfectly in Excel. +1 and accepting.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. :) I know it's actually bad practice. I've tried my hand in C and the typing is too strong. However, VBA especially in Excel has a bit of... "quirkiness" to it. :D

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to do a global replace ctl h. Replace the . with nothing

Comment: As simple as it sounds, this would work too, although I prefer the automation approach, i.e. data is pasted in raw, then converted on the fly. +1 for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

DateValue will only work with the right Regional Settings, We get an error if we try to open it in a computer with different settings. This will always work: (text date in G21)

```
=DATE(RIGHT(G21;4);MATCH(1;1*(LEFT(G21;3)={"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"});0);MID(G21;FIND(",";G21)-2;2))
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

Comment: I plan to be running this on my home PC only, which is using `English (US)`, but thanks for a hint. +1.